# Cannot set a force_override via knife node edit

Tags: chef-infra

Using `knife node edit -a nodename`, it doesn't seem that I can set a force_override attribute. I get the message:

> Node not updated, skipping node save

Other levels like `default` are ok to be edited though. Is it not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is structurally impossible, all levels other than normal are rebuilt from scratch every converge to prevent stragglers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/core/node_editor.rb#L60-L70), it looks like it doesn't let you do that.